# jquery each selector and ajax not producing the right results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to simplify my code but running into issues where it is not working when it place in an each loop.

Here is what I am trying to do:
- html has *n* parent DIV that generates a report via an AJAX call to pull data
- each div respective to report utilizes a data attribute to define which report to pull
- based no the results of the report, it should populate the html with the respective results.

HTML Code (to simplify, using n = 2):

```
<div class="widget-box widget-hits card no-border bg-white no-margin" data-widget-report="widget-hits">
  <div class="container-xs-height full-height">
    <div class="row-xs-height">
      <div class="col-xs-height col-top">
        <div class="card-header top-left top-right">
          <div class="card-title text-black hint-text">
            <span class="font-montserrat fs-11 all-caps">Weekly Hits
                      <i class="far fa-chevron-right p-l-5"></i>
                    </span>
          </div>
          <div class="card-controls">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a data-toggle="refresh" class="card-refresh text-black" href="#">
                  <i class="far fa-circle fa-xs"></i>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-xs-height ">
      <div class="col-xs-height col-top relative">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="p-l-20 widget-total">
              <h3 class="no-margin p-b-5"></h3>
              <p class="small hint-text m-t-5">
                <span class="label m-r-5">%</span>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="widget-chart"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="widget-box widget-sales card no-border bg-white no-margin" data-widget-report="widget-sales">
  <div class="container-xs-height full-height">
    <div class="row-xs-height">
      <div class="col-xs-height col-top">
        <div class="card-header top-left top-right">
          <div class="card-title text-black hint-text">
            <span class="font-montserrat fs-11 all-caps">Weekly Sales
                      <i class="far fa-chevron-right p-l-5"></i>
                    </span>
          </div>
          <div class="card-controls">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a data-toggle="refresh" class="card-refresh text-black" href="#">
                  <i class="far fa-circle fa-xs"></i>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-xs-height ">
      <div class="col-xs-height col-top relative">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="p-l-20 widget-total">
              <h3 class="no-margin p-b-5"></h3>
              <p class="small hint-text m-t-5">
                <span class="label m-r-5">%</span>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="widget-chart"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.widget-box').each(function() {
  $widget_report = $(this).data('widget-report');
  if ($widget_report !== undefined) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: '/admin/reports/' + $widget_report,
      dataType: 'json',
      success:
        function(data) {
          if (data.success) {
            var labelsData = [];
            var seriesData = [];
            var trend = data.trend * 100;
            widget_class = '.' + $widget_report + ' .widget-chart';
            console.log(widget_class);
            $(this).find('.widget-total h3').text(data.total);
            $(this).find('.widget-total p span').text(trend + '%');
            trend_span = $(this).find('.widget-total p').children('span');
            if(data.trend  > 0) {
              $(this).find('.widget-total p span.label').addClass('label-success');
              $(this).find('.widget-total p').text('Higher');
            }
            else {
              $(this).find('.widget-total p span.label').addClass('label-important'); 
              $(this).find('.widget-total p').text('Lower');
            }
            $(this).find('.widget-total p').prepend(trend_span);
            $.each(data.values, function(key, value){
              date = new Date(value.label + 'T00:00:00');
              labelsData.push(date.getMonth() + 1 + '/' + date.getDate());
              seriesData.push(value.value);
            });
            chartData = {
              labels: labelsData,
              series: [seriesData]
            }

            alert(widget_class);

            new Chartist.Bar(widget_class, chartData, {
              axisX: {
                showGrid: false
              },
              axisY: {
                showGrid: false,
                showLabel: false
              }
            });
          }
        }
    });
  }
});
```

Here are the problems I've encountered:

1. $(this).find('.widget-total h3').text is not updating the respective DIV group
2. widget_class for some reason is always returning the last DIV group... even if the last DIV group was returning data.success = false. Ex: above would return widget-sales twice and not widget-hits and then widget-sales.

I am scratching my head on this one... I am able to get this to work without the .each loop and distinctively create one for each... but was hoping to make this universal and allow the control rely on the data-widget-report attribute on the html.

Is this the proper approach?

Any help / direction is appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `var` in front of `widget_class` and `$widget_report` so they are scoped to the function instead of global. I think that will fix your problem. Right now `$widget_report` gets replaced by the last widget even before the ajax calls are completed.

As for the `$(this)` not working, you have to assign it to a variable before you make the ajax call.

```
$('.widget-box').each(function() {
  var widgetBoxElement = $(this);
  var $widget_report = $(this).data('widget-report');
  if ($widget_report !== undefined) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: '/admin/reports/' + $widget_report,
      dataType: 'json',
      success:
        function(data) {
          if (data.success) {
           // use widgetBoxElement here instead of $(this)

          }
        }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: omg, that did it. Thank you. 
Any hints or suggestion on the $(this) not finding the elements to update the text within the success function?

Comment: dude, super... thank you. 
Interesting enough, wondering why... i am assuming once it goes in to .ajax $(this) gets assigned to a different object?

Comment: @Rick that's correct, this changes based on the function you are in.